# Struts2 File Download Permission Denied

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat

I have a Struts2 webapp that is running on a Tomcat 7 server. What I'm trying to do is allow a user to download a file from the server.

When running the Eclipse Tomcat server and accessing localhost, I have no issues downloading the files.

However when I deploy onto my server, when clicking on the download link, I get the following exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/tmp/myFile.pdf (Permission denied)
    java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    com.my.path.to.action.UpdateAction.execute(UpdateAction.java:201)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:446)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:285)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:238)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:238)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:544)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
```

Here is my action to download the file

**Action.java**

```
private InputStream fileInputStream;

    public InputStream getFileInputStream() {
        return fileInputStream;
    }

public String execute() throws Exception {
        File fileToDownload = new File("/var/tmp/myFile.pdf");
        System.out.print(fileToDownload.getName());
        fileName = fileToDownload.getName();
        contentLength = fileToDownload.length();
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileToDownload);
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

I've checked on the file to make sure the file exists at the specified location and it does. I've also entered an incorrect file name and I get an error saying that it can't find the specified file (which means that it can read the directory and determine that it doesn't exist.)

Here is my struts.

**Struts.xml**

```
<action name="download" class="com.my.path.to.action.UpdateAction">
        <result name="success" type="stream">
                <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename=${fileName}</param>
                <param name="contentType">application/doc</param>
                <param name="inputName">fileInputStream</param>
                <param name="bufferSize">4096</param>
                <param name="contentLength">${contentLength}</param>
        </result>
</action>
```

To make sure no one is confused, I do obviously changed the path in which the files are accessed between the Windows path (which works) and the Linux path (which doesn't).

Additionally, the server is running on an Ubuntu 12.04 server. If this question should be relocated to a different forum, please let me know.

Comment: What are the permissions/ownership on `/var/tmp/myFile.pdf`?

Comment: /var/tmp is 777 by default. running ls -l shows that it's wide open.
rwxrwxrwx 1 user user 7753786 Jul 19 11:38 myFile.pdf

Answer (score 0):

This is a Linux permissions issue. Your Tomcat server is running as a system user. This user doesn't have permission to the path  **/var/tmp/** . You need a system administrator to determine the user that's running Tomcat and then provide access to /var/tmp. And, yes, this question is NOT a Java question, but a system one.

Comment: I thought this as well. I made a group and changed the group of /var/tmp to it. I then added the Tomcat user to that group. I thought that would have solved the problem, but it has not. Isn't the user "Tomcat" what should have been added. If not what is the default user that Tomcat runs under.

Comment: The user you mentioned was "Tomcat" ... that should really be lowercase. Look in the startup script for Tomcat and you should find the username. If you don't know how to do this, you should move this question to the system admin stack site. Your /var/tmp may be off-limits for general users. Are you responsible for this server or is it your local machine?  Anyhow, this is not a Java question.You should move this discussion.

Comment: When I said "Tomcat" that was a typo. I added the user "tomcat7". I'm responsible for the server as our sys admin is on vactation (yay). I'll move this to askUbuntu. Thanks.